# Word macro to change page color

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, macros

I am attempting to create a Word macro (Microsoft Word Professional 10) to change the page background color. I began by recording the keystrokes - this is the recorded macro:

```
---
Sub WritingLayout()
'
' WritingLayout Macro
'
    ActiveDocument.Background.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    ActiveDocument.Background.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 43, 56)
    ActiveDocument.Background.Fill.Solid
End Sub
---
```

This macro does not work on new documents. Once the page background color has been set, the macro works. Looking at the xml files, the only difference I can find is that after the page background has been set, there is an xml element `<w:displayBackgroundShape/>` in the settings.xml file. Could this be the cause of the macro failure? If so, how do I set this in a macro?

Comment: When you mean it doesn't work on new document, what exactly you do? Close and open the macro recorded document?

Comment: No. The macro is saved in 'Normal.dotm' -- the default template for new documents. Upon creating a new document, the macro does not change the page color. If I manually set the page color and then change it back, the macro will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding this line and running the macro with the document open in Print View inserts the settings.xml Element:

```
activedocument.ActiveWindow.View.DisplayBackgrounds = True
```

(Not easily deduced from the recorded code!)